# How to import a JS file in another JS file in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have got this node server and a bunch of JS classes in my js directory. I want to create a file called "exports.js" that exports all the classes required by server (using exports.Classname = class notation). However, the problem is that exports.js doesn't have access to the classes. I was wondering what's the correct syntax for importing the whole ES6 class in another file. So far I have tried following with no luck:

```
//I want to import User class from User.js
import "./User.js"; 
import "User";
import "./User";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: Not that it makes any difference but please note that I am using Babel transpiler.

Comment: If using babel, then `import` is fine. If not, you have to use `require()`. Babel transforms `import` in `require()`

Comment: Of the three given, what's the correct syntax for import?

Comment: Did you read the MDN documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import . It lists all the possible ways how to import a module.

Comment: Use the last one. But first you need to do `export default [YOUR CLASS]` in the file your define `User`.

Comment: Also, if you want to use / reference the class after import you should use `import User from './User'`, then you can reference it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
// user.js
class user{
    ...
}
export default user

// another js
import user from './user.js'
```